# What would be the better way to automate generating access token for Connected App salesforce API once they expire

Tags: oauth-2.0, salesforce, access-token, refresh-token

Current Challenge:

Lead(customer) fills their details in a form and the front-end client uploads it to the Salesforce CRM platform as a Lead object through this API:

`<instance_url>/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Lead?Authorization=Bearer <access_token>`

Note:

The problem is, that the `access_token` is going to expire, and will need new valid access tokens.

I have two ways of going about it:

1. Get a new access token through this endpoint: `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/token?username=<username>&password=<password><secret_token>&grant_type=password&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>`. Extract new access token from its response and use it to create a new POST request to `/Lead`.
2. Use the refresh token to get a new `access_token` once it expires.

2 Looks like a better plan but the only method I saw to get `refresh_token` [here](https://documentation.sailpoint.com/connectors/identityiq8_3/salesforce/help/integrating_salesforce/generating_refresh_token.html) and [here](https://medium.com/@bpmmendis94/obtain-access-refresh-tokens-from-salesforce-rest-api-a324fe4ccd9b) requires manual interaction, which I do not want.

Should I just go with option 1 to keep the whole process automated, or is there any other way to go about option 2(if it's better, that is) without manually logging in at any point when the refresh token expires?

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.connected_app_client_credentials_setup.htm&type=5

This allows getting access token through client_credentials flow, to manual interaction needed